# How do I stop my text from cycling through the array when the user clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have text that is randomly generated when the user clicks on the screen. Everything works with the movement, color, etc, except it just constantly cycles through the array changing the word. How do I get it to choose a word at random each time the user clicks and keep that word on screen without cycling through the array? Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var canvas;
var context;
var texts = [];
var timer;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    resizeCanvas();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);

    canvas.onclick = function(event) {
        handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }

    var timer = setInterval(resizeCanvas, 30);
}

function Text(x,y,textColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.textColor = textColor;

        this.vx = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
        this.vy = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
        this.time = 300;
}

function handleClick(x,y) {
        var colors = [[255,0,0],[255,255,0],[0,0,255]];
        var textColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        texts.push(new Text(x,y,textColor));
        for (var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
            drawText(texts[i]);
        }
}

function timeToFade(time) {
    if(time > 100) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return time / 100;
    }
}

function drawText(text) {
     context.font = "bold 60px Verdana";
     var textSayings = ['Cool!', 'Nice!', 'Awesome!', 'Wow!', 'Whoa!', 'Super!', 'Woohoo!', 'Yay!', 'Yeah!']
     var whichText = textSayings[Math.floor(Math.random()*textSayings.length)];

     var c = text.textColor
     context.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c[0] + ', ' + c[1] + ', ' + c[2] + ', ' + (text.time / 100) + ')';
     context.fillText(whichText,text.x,text.y); 
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth-20;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight-20;
    fillBackgroundColor();
    for (var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
        var te = texts[i];
        drawText(te);

        if (te.x + te.vx > canvas.width || te.x + te.vx < 0)
            te.vx = -te.vx
        if (te.y + te.vy > canvas.height || te.y + te.vy < 0)
            te.vy = -te.vy
        if (te.time === 0) {
            texts.splice(i,1);
        }

        te.time -= 3;
        te.x += te.vx;
        te.y += te.vy;
    }
}

function fillBackgroundColor() {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the word picking logic out of the drawing function. Just pick a word before entering the loop, and pass that word to the draw function which only job will be to actually draw some stuff.

You could do something like this :

```js
var canvas;
var context;
var texts = [];
var timer;
var textSayings = ['Cool!', 'Nice!', 'Awesome!', 'Wow!', 'Whoa!', 'Super!', 'Woohoo!', 'Yay!', 'Yeah!']

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  resizeCanvas();
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);

  canvas.onclick = function(event) {
    handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  }

  var timer = setInterval(resizeCanvas, 30);
}

function Text(x, y, textColor, word) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.word = word;
  this.textColor = textColor;

  this.vx = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
  this.vy = Math.random() * 30 - 15;
  this.time = 300;
}

function handleClick(x, y) {
  var colors = [
    [255, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 0],
    [0, 0, 255]
  ];
  var textColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  texts.push(new Text(
    x,
    y,
    textColor,
    pickWord()
  ));
  for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    drawText(texts[i]);
  }
}

function timeToFade(time) {
  if (time > 100) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return time / 100;
  }
}

function pickWord() {
  return textSayings[Math.floor(Math.random() * textSayings.length)];
}

function drawText(text) {
  context.font = "bold 60px Verdana";

  var c = text.textColor
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + c[0] + ', ' + c[1] + ', ' + c[2] + ', ' + (text.time / 100) + ')';
  context.fillText(text.word, text.x, text.y);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
  fillBackgroundColor();
  for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    var te = texts[i];
    drawText(te);

    if (te.x + te.vx > canvas.width || te.x + te.vx < 0)
      te.vx = -te.vx
    if (te.y + te.vy > canvas.height || te.y + te.vy < 0)
      te.vy = -te.vy
    if (te.time === 0) {
      texts.splice(i, 1);
    }

    te.time -= 3;
    te.x += te.vx;
    te.y += te.vy;
  }
}

function fillBackgroundColor() {
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
}

window.onload = init;
init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Note that I added a `word` property to the `Text` class, and a `pickWord` function that chooses a word from the global list.